# Source for email address fields

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

I use Outlook 2016. When I prepare to send an email and introduce the first letter(s), the program suggests addresses already used. The source of them is NOT Address Book or Contacts.
Where are they stored and how can I manage them?

Comment: It's the "TO " box remembering/auto-completing them, and you're correct in realizing that it's an independent list. In what way(s) are you looking to "mange" them exactly?

Comment: I, personally, would like to remove ones that are no longer correct.

Answer (score 0):

This is AutoComplete list. It is stored right inside your mailbox. Outlook doesn't provide standard tools for managing AutoComplete lists. You can only clear them or remove entries one by one (click X next to each entry).

There is a pair of free tools: [Export Auto-Complete Lists](https://www.outlookfreeware.com/en/products/all/OutlookAutoCompleteExport/) and [Import Auto-Complete List](http://www.outlookfreeware.com/en/products/all/OutlookAutoCompleteImport). You can use them to export autocomplete to XML file, edit it using any text editor (like Notepad) and import back. I recommend these tools because I'm one of the developers.